# Formally writing "$f(x,y)=z$ can be solved for $x$"?

Tags: functions, notation

I wonder what the formal way to write "$f(x,y)=z$ can be solved for $x$"?

Maybe something like this:

Let $f\colon X\times Y\to Z, f(x,y)=z$ be such that there exists $g\colon Y\times Z\to X, g(y,z)=x$.

However, I feel that this hides the "solved for" part.

Comment: Is there a reason you would need a formal notation for such a thing? Oftentimes, it's just easier to say what you mean -- it's easier for the reader to parse through (since solving for a variable is a familiar notion), and it's easier for you to write (because you don't have hangups like these). Writing mathematically involves words just as much as it does symbols, after all.

Comment: Basically, you have an *expression* $\varphi(x,y,z)$. To "solve for $x$ an equation" based on that expression means : "to find $x_0$ (maybe depending on $y$ and $z$) such that $\varphi(x_0,y,z)=0$. Thus, the oepration of "solving" amounts to verify if (for suitable conditions) $\exists x [\varphi(x,y,z)=0]$ holds.

Comment: @EEvee Trainer: I agree that simple explanations should be used. However, is nice to know what alternatives exists.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: I understand.

Comment: Thank you both!